# SQL Server remove EXCEPT and just have in WHERE/AND statements

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have the following SQL that I want to refactor and remove the EXCEPT

The SQL chunk is as follows:

```
UPDATE pv SET pv.EndDate = @newEndDate, pv.AuditUser = @auditUser
FROM PriceValues pv
INNER JOIN Prices p ON pv.PriceId = p.Id
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT Id FROM #RowsIWant 
            EXCEPT
            SELECT p.Id
            FROM PriceValues pv
            INNER JOIN #RowsIWant AS p ON pv.PriceId = p.Id
            WHERE pv.StartDate > @currentExpiryDate
            AND @newEndDate >= pv.StartDate
) up ON p.Id = up.Id
WHERE pv.EndDate = @currentExpiryDate
AND p.Active = 1
```

How can I remove the EXCEPT and just add extra AND's to the bottom

Originally I though I could just reverse the greater than symbols like this example, but I'm not convinced this is right and my mind cant seem to figure it out!

```
UPDATE pv SET pv.EndDate = @newEndDate, pv.AuditUser = @auditUser
FROM #RowsIWant AS P
INNER JOIN PriceValues AS PV ON pv.PriceId = P.PriceId
WHERE pv.EndDate = @currentExpiryDate
AND pv.StartDate < @currentExpiryDate
AND @newEndDate <= pv.StartDate
AND p.Active = 1
```

Comment: This seems logically the same -- did you get different results?

Comment: Yes I go different results, I used the NOT EXIST Approach as mentioned by Charliseface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the first part to a normal join, and the second half to `NOT EXISTS`

```sql
UPDATE pv
SET pv.EndDate = @newEndDate,
    pv.AuditUser = @auditUser
FROM PriceValues pv
INNER JOIN Prices p ON pv.PriceId = p.Id
INNER JOIN #RowsIWant riw ON p.Id = riw.Id
WHERE pv.EndDate = @currentExpiryDate
  AND p.Active = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM PriceValues pv2
    WHERE pv2.PriceId = p.Id
      AND pv2.StartDate > @currentExpiryDate
      AND @newEndDate >= pv2.StartDate
  )
```

You could also use `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` like the other answer, but that is generally not as efficient.

Don't fall into the trap of using `NOT IN`, because it doesn't deal well with nulls.

Comment: I tried the LEFT JOIN, NULL Approach but that didnt work, but the NOT EXISTS did work. So will stick with this approach, many thanks

Comment: "generally not as efficient" - that has to be backed-up by execution plan

Comment: @YosiDahari IME majority of execution plans work better with a `NOT EXISTS` rather than `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`, partly due to the optimizer deducing that there is never more than one row being returned, and therefore maintaining the uniqueness and ordering of the data flow, it cannot do this with a `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
SELECT Id FROM #RowsIWant 
EXCEPT
SELECT p.Id
FROM PriceValues pv
INNER JOIN #RowsIWant AS p ON pv.PriceId = p.Id
WHERE pv.StartDate > @currentExpiryDate
AND @newEndDate >= pv.StartDate
```

Is logically equivalent to:

```
SELECT p.Id
FROM #RowsIWant  pv
LEFT JOIN PriceValues AS p ON pv.PriceId = p.Id
WHERE pv.Id IS NULL 
    AND pv.StartDate > @currentExpiryDate
    AND @newEndDate >= pv.StartDate
```

The basic concept is that you can use left join, to find where there isn't a match.

Comment: Thanks this one I tried but it didnt seem to work, the below answer with the NOT EXISTS Seemed to work giving me the same results